# How do I populate the File member of a ListItem using the client object model Sharepoint 2013 API?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When you execute a query on a List that is a Document Library, ListItems have a File member that is not populated. Obviously the query doesn't pull in all data by default for performance reasons, but I can't figure out a way to tell the query to populate the File Member, since the query syntax is generic for all Lists and only Document Libraries contain files in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve ListItem with File property initialized it should be specified explicitly via [ClientRuntimeContext.Load Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536388%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
private static ListItem GetListItem(string url, ICredentials creds, string listTitle, int listItemId)
{
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
    {
        clientContext.Credentials = creds;

        var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
        clientContext.Load(list);
        clientContext.Load(listItem, i => i.File); //specify File property 
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        return listItem;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample code should help you out:

```
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var itemFile = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Shared Documents").getItemById(1).get_file();

    ctx.load(itemFile);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    console.log(itemFile.get_title());

    },function(sender,args){

    console.log(args.get_message());

    });
```